# Spring Boot JSONP with MappingJacksonValue response and strict MIME type error

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jsonp

I've been reading a lot about JSONP support with Spring 4, but I still lack a clean explanation to make it work with the right media-type (under chrome)

1) I **added the JsonpAdvice** cfr [Jackson JSONP Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-jsonp)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {
    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super("callback");
    }
}
```

2) My controller is **wrapping the response with MappingJacksonValue***

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/api/test', method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result.add("hello");
    result.add("world");
    if(request.getParameter('callback')){
        MappingJacksonValue value = new MappingJacksonValue(result)
        value.setJsonpFunction(request.getParameter('callback'))
        return value
    }
    return result
}
```

not sure the MappingJacksonValue is necessary or if MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter will take care of that?

3) I added explicit **media-types in application.yml**:

```
spring:
  profiles.active: development
  jackson.property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
  mvc:
    media-types:
      json: 'application/json'
      xml:  'application/xml'
      jsonp: 'application/javascript'
```

However I still get the **following error in Chrome**:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/api/test?callback=jQuery22406993800323428312_1481922214995&_=1481922214996'
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Any step missing? or too much configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging my JsonpAdvice.groovy, I found out that AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice is expecting a list of String: private final String[] jsonpQueryParamNames;

My initial code was using a simple String. Here is the fix:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {
    public JsonpAdvice() {
        super(["callback"])
    }
}
```